# AJAX call : JQuery ok but Vue and Vanilla JS not executing script inside element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I would like to execute a code inside an html element after an xhr request

I used to used JQUERY `$(el).html(data)` and that worked just fine

Now trying to get rid of jquery

I tried both vanilla JS `innerHTML` and vue3 `v-html` but the script never executes

I can see it in html

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    axios.get('/getAarea/blog')
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data;
          if (!data.report) {
            const el = $("#ContentUserPanel")
            el.html(data)
            this.loading = false
            this.selected = this.types.blogs
            this.toggleUserMobileMenu()
          } else {
            Error('There was an error ',data.report)
            this.loading = false
            this.selected = null
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          Error('There was an error ',err)
          this.loading = false
          this.selected = null
        });
```

Could someone explain ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @tromgy none, nothing; just nothing happens

Comment: Please post your code as well (better as text, not screenshots). In Vue you should put your initialization in the components (`mounted()` or `created()`).

Comment: @PeterKrebs I added the code; it is not possible for me to use `mounted()` or `created()` because this is an ajax call

Comment: I have all my ajax calls to load resources in my `mounted()`. I create a method, which I call in `mounted()`. Do you get an error?

Comment: No error. I can't use mounted since this is asynchronus